# Load user control when document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I have a web page that has a user control in it and it loads a tree in the page. The problem is, that since the user control is loading at the same time the page is loading the page is really slow. How can I have a loading wheel where the treee is and load the user control using jquery when the document ready event is triggered? Problem is, how can i tell when the user control has finished loading so i can remove the loading wheel and display the tree generated user control.

I yet lack the knowledge to optimize the queries made by the user control so that option is disregarded. Please let me know if using the document ready is the best way to do it or if there is a more efficient way please.

Comment: Please remove reluctance to gain knowledge on how to optimize UserControl. After that, you should look into Ajax. There's no easy way of loading a UserControl asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showBusyGif();
    $.ajax({
        url:urlToUserControl
        //data:string,
        async:true,
        success: function(result){
            hideBusyGif();
            showUserTree();
        }
    });     
});
```